# SCM-Manager: importing own repositories

Tags: svn, version-control, repository, scmmanager

I have installed SCM-Manager v1.32 and now I want to import my old subversion repositories I created with Tortoise. I looked around the documentation and did not found where to upload the repository files. Any suggestions to that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Importing your existing repositories is very easy. SCM-Manager stores them into the .scm path that is located in the home directory of the running user.
If you are under windows copy your repository files to .scm\repositories\svn
After this, start your SCM-Manager server and click on "Import repositories" at the left menu.  Activate the checkbox for svn repositories. The new repositories will be displayed immediately.

Comment: In newer versions of SCM-Manager (and on Linux) the home path can also be `/var/lib/scm` - see https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/wiki/RPM%20and%20DEB%20packages